# How to open a new Internet explorer from command prompt with no ToolBar ,AdressBar and Standard Buttons?

Tags: internet-explorer

I need to open a new IE window form console ,

currently i am opening a new window from java by executing the following command from code.

```
 C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -new "www.google.com"
```

Is it possible to disable the Toolbar , AdressBar etc with a command similar to as above...?

Answer (score 4):

Use kiosk mode of IE.

To see sample of how it works, run the below command in run prompt.

```
        iexplore -k www.google.com
```